# Clear a text box if validation fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

I am trying to clear two different text boxes when the compare validation fails. I have tried doing it using the .clear method in the C# code but VS won't allow it in a web form. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and have hardly any asp.net experience. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried clearing the text box multiple ways when user presses 'Submit' in the Else statement of the validator.isvalid. But it seems that the procedure won't fire unless the entire page is valid.

Here's the code for the submit button:

```
    If valCompPassword.IsValid Then
        If Page.IsValid Then
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & txtNameFull.Text & "!"
        End If
    Else
        txtPassword.Text = ""
    End If
```

Is there anyway to bypass the validation and fire the procedure?

Comment: Post some code of what you've tried..it helps.

Comment: If `.clear` does not work, have you tried `texbox.text = "";`?

Comment: Yes I have, It doesn't work with the validator there.

Comment: Just did, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the property of the control (i.e. TextBox, Button etc) **CausesValidation**? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx

Comment: I actually did try that before and it didn't work but I just tried it again with some changes to the code and it seems to work fine. I don't even need the code to clear the text box. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the 'Causes validation' property of the submit button to false clears the password text boxes. Not quite sure why or how it just clears those I assume it is clearing the text boxes with the 'Text mode' property set to password. If you still want to validate using the button you must use the 'Page.Validate' procedure within your button click code.

Here's the C# code for the button:

```
    Page.Validate()
    If Page.IsValid Then
        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & txtNameFull.Text & "!"
    End If
```